# Flask on Apache Server for Windows with HTML template Files

Tags: windows, apache, python-2.7, flask

I was hoping to get help on an issue that I am having. I am trying to deploy Flask to an Apache server. My flask uses the render template function in order to display HTML pages. I've gotten it to work on my Localhost, but now as I am trying to deploy it to the Apache server, but I am not sure about where to put the HTML files for flask to recognize. I setup my mod_wsgi to work properly with displaying a flask file that does not use HTML files, but could someone tell me where to place the files and what I am supposed to type into the httpd.conf file? Thanks you for reading my post

This is how my httpd file is set up with the wsgi, static and template tht isnt working

httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "C:/wsgi_app/test.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/wsgi_app">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


Alias /static "C:/wsgi_app/static"
<Directory "C:/wsgi_app/static">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /templates "C:/wsgi_app/templates"
<Directory "C:/wsgi_app/templates">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is the current setup for where my files are

File Directory:

```
--C://
  --wsgi-app/
    --test.wsgi
    --test.py
    --static/
    --templates/
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Your directory structure looks correct. Apache doesn't serve the templates files, so you don't need to include them in your Apache config.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am receiving Error 500 Internal Server Error